# Difference between the ways of function calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I have noticed that (at least in React) there are different ways to call a function. I'd say:

```
onClick={myFunction}
onClick={myFunction()}
onClick={()=>myFunction}
onClick={()=>myFunction()} /*Not sure if I've seen this type*/
```

Being the case all are correct, what are the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> onClick={myFunction}
> ```

Assigns `myFunction` to `onClick`.

---

> ```
> onClick={myFunction()}
> ```

Calls `myFunction` immediately and assigns the return value (which needs to be another function) to `onClick`.

This is often an error caused by people not understanding how `()` works and wanting the previous syntax.

---

> ```
> onClick={()=>myFunction}
> ```

Creates a new function and assigns it to `onClick`.

The new function mentions `myFunction` but doesn't do anything with it. It is a [noop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_(code)).

It is always a mistake.

---

> ```
> onClick={()=>myFunction()}
> ```

Creates a new function, which calls `myFunction`, and assigns it to `onClick`.

This is usually a waste of resources. It is useful only if `myFunction` would do something with the event object that `onClick` passes to the event handler when called and you want to prevent that.

If you were to pass arguments to `myFunction` (which this example does not) then it would be more generally useful.

Comment: That was a very complete answer, thank you. What's the difference between assign  a func to click  or call it? doesn't do the same?

Comment: @Germán — It's the difference between "do something" and "do something when I click the button"

Comment: A good rehashing of the explanation in TJ Crowder's answer to the dupe...